# Positive real number M such that for all n $|a_n|$ less than M

Tags: analysis

[Click on the link to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8rhi.jpg)

In this problem I have integrated the expression |f'(x) | to get $f(x)$<$x/2$ but after that how to proceed with the problem is clueless.Kindly help.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate from a few months back. Can't find the question though

Comment: Yes.... I have got it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Show by induction, using MVT, that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}|a_1-a_0|$$

Deduce that the sequence $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, and hence, is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

$|f(x)-f(0)| \leq \frac 1 2 |x|$ so $|f(x)| \leq c+\frac {|x|} 2$ where $c=|f(0)|$. So $|a_{n+1}| \leq c+\frac {|a_n|} 2$. This gives $|a_{n+1}| \leq c(1+\frac 1 2)+ \frac {|a_{n-1}|} {2^{2}}$ and so on. Finally we get $|a_{n+1}| \leq c(1+\frac  1 2+\frac 1 {2^{2}}+...+\frac 1 {2^{n-1}})+\frac {|a_1|} {2^{n}}$. Can you finish?